# requestLocation() fails to provide Course on watch hardware but work in Sim

Tags: gps, watchkit, core-location

I've written a standalone Applewatch app which uses GPS. Trying to be a good citizen and minimize power consumption, I am using the single shot location request method.  On the Xcode sim, this works fine, providing a location AND course and speed (when using one of the recorded movements in the sim).  On real hardware, I get accurate lat and long data back but course always returns "-1". Note: I am not looking for Heading data as there is no magnetometer hardware in watch.  I want course over the ground from ∆X,Y from the GPS fixes.  Expected behavior is that it should not work in Sim with a single shot requestLocation(), but since it does, why not work on the real thing?  Has anyone else seen this? Is this a bug to Radar, or a feature?

I suppose if this approach is known to fail, I could try startUpdating() until I see a course, then stop updating, but Apple says this is a power hogging approach.

Comment: Continuing with experiments, it appears that the course issue is dependent on the properties of the instance of CLLocationManager: when         locationMgr.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer
        locationMgr.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
        locationMgr.activityType = .otherNavigation        No course reported by hardware(Sim does report), \nbut when         locationMgr.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationMgr.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
        locationMgr.activityType = .otherNavigation
, then the watch does report course.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing with experiments, it appears that the course issue is dependent on the properties of the instance of CLLocationManager: when

```
locationMgr.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer
locationMgr.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
locationMgr.activityType = .otherNavigation  



No course reported by hardware(Sim does report),but when

locationMgr.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
locationMgr.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
locationMgr.activityType = .otherNavigation
```

then the watch does report course.  It would seem that .DistanceFilter should be relevant to ∆X,∆Y reports for course, but why should .desiredAccuracy matter?

BTW, original code had Accuracy of 1km due Apple noting increasing accuracy increases power drain.